# Every other rectangle detects the collison in my Java FX game

Tags: javafx, collision-detection

Okay so I have this little mock up game of clash royale and when I click to spawn a character and move him across the bridge on pane, I have a enemy on the bridge and my character stops as he should.

BUT, if I click to spawn my second character BEFORE he gets to enemy then the FIRST character moves through enemy and goes to tower.

Now, what I want to do is detect for every character, and they should all act the same. Not too sure what is going on here but I am needing a little assistance as this is the first game I've really made before.

```
private void createCharacter(CHARACTER choosenCharacter) {
    gamePane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            if (elixir > 4) {
                character = new ImageView(choosenCharacter.getUrl());
                healthbar = new Rectangle(50.0, 10.0, Color.BLUE);

                character.setLayoutX(event.getSceneX() - 40);
                character.setLayoutY(event.getSceneY() - 110);

                healthbar.setLayoutX(event.getSceneX() - 40);
                healthbar.setLayoutY(event.getSceneY() - 110);

                System.out.println(event.getSceneX() + "\n" + event.getSceneY());
                elixir = elixir - 6;

                if (detectCollision()){
                 gameTimer.stop();
                }
                createGameLoop(character, healthbar);
                gamePane.getChildren().add(character);
                gamePane.getChildren().add(healthbar);

            }
        }
    });

}

private void moveCharacter(ImageView character, Rectangle health) {   
    if (character.getLayoutX() > 180 && character.getLayoutX() < 450) {
        character.setLayoutX(character.getLayoutX() - 2);
    }
    if (health.getLayoutX() > 180 && health.getLayoutX() < 450) {
        health.setLayoutX(health.getLayoutX() - 2);  
    }

    if (character.getLayoutX() <= 200 && character.getLayoutY() > 2) {
        character.setLayoutY(character.getLayoutY() - 2);

    }
    if (health.getLayoutX() <= 200 && health.getLayoutY() > 2) {
        health.setLayoutY(health.getLayoutY() - 2); 
    }

    if (character.getLayoutX() < 700 && character.getLayoutX() >= 450) {
        character.setLayoutX(character.getLayoutX() + 2);
    }
    if (health.getLayoutX() < 700 && health.getLayoutX() >= 450) {
        health.setLayoutX(health.getLayoutX() + 2);
    }

    if (character.getLayoutX() >= 700 && character.getLayoutY() > 2) {
        character.setLayoutY(character.getLayoutY() - 2);
    }
    if (health.getLayoutX() >= 700 && health.getLayoutY() > 2) {
        health.setLayoutY(health.getLayoutY() - 2);
    }
}

private void createGameLoop(ImageView character, Rectangle health) {
    gameTimer = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (detectCollision()){
             gameTimer.stop();
            }
            moveCharacter(character, health);

        }
    };

    gameTimer.start();
}
```

As you can see it's not the cleanest code but I need some way to detect each instance of my game character and I'm just not able to think of how to solve this little problem of mine. Any suggestions on how to handle something like this would be greatfully appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The `detectCollision` method seems pretty relevant to the problem, don't you think? Please [edit] the question and include it. It's a bit suspicious that you don't pass `character` (or some other info) to this method though. Probably you're refering to a field there which seems to contain the last one created. I'd recommend using a `List` to contain all characters and restrict yourself to a single `AnimationTimer` btw. This way it's much simpler to control when the updates/checks happen.

Comment: [mcve] please ..